# Почему некоторые пакеты в java начинаются с com. ? что такое com?

Tags: java

Почему некоторые пакеты в java начинаются с com. ? что такое com ?
например, com.oracle.jdbc

Answer (score 5):

Это просто определение пространства имен, чтобы избежать столкновения имен классов. com.domain.package.Class -это установленное соглашение Java, в котором пространство имен квалифицируется с доменом компании в обратном порядке (то есть, имя пространства имён `com.oracle.jdbc` в перевернутом виде превратится в более привычное `jdbc.oracle.com` - что уже очень похоже на "имя сайта, куда надо ходить за jdbc драйвером для оракла").

[источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411717/why-do-package-names-often-begin-with-com)

Comment: еще можете почитать вот это:https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_package#Package_naming_conventions

Comment: Б л а г о д а р ю !             :)